# What is "ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions" in the new flash player 14?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There's an error when I use ExternalInterface as below:

> WARNING: For content targeting Flash Player version 14 or higher,
>   ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions. To maintain
>   compatibility, content published to earlier Flash Player versions
>   continues to use the legacy escaping behavior.

What should I do to prevent the warning to show up and what's "legacy escaping" that I should use instead of "JSON convention"?

Comment: Anyone know how to remove the warning message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning appears in the debugger console when strings are sent from a running SWF to JavaScript which contain forbidden characters.  This may also affect whether deep linking works as expected.

Both the **ExternalInterface** and **BrowserManager** APIs are effected.  If using the escape() method alone is not enough to eliminate the warning, try:

```
escape(str).replace(/\./g, "%2E").replace(/\:/g, "%3A").replace(/\//g, "%2F");
```

Comment: This answer fixes a lot more cases where the warning appears, oppossed to [Dave Bleeker's anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28093823/244557) which only removes it from some of them.

Answer (score 10):

The error is caused because of json data not escaped.
You can prevent the error simply by escaping it:

```
ExternalInterface.call(callBackFunction, escape(jsonData));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is so much better of an answer than the accepted answer.  Upvote.

Comment: Using the additional `replace`'s from [CQ Bear's anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30202542/244557) eliminates the warning in all cases I've found, opposed to this one just solving some of them.

Comment: I'm passing objects back and forth from AS to JS and JS to AS and it's not practical or always possible to escape all the objects and data. I don't know if escaping it is what Adobe is suggesting to begin with. The message is saying the encoding method has changed. It doesn't say that it's broken. At a really low level data was sent in an XML like format http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7caf.html. Now it is sent as JSON. But in the browser this is done behind the scenes. So the message should be turned off.

Answer (score -4):

In general you should avoid anything with the word "legacy" unless you have a very good reason

Good reasons include but are not limited too:

1. The effort to convert old code away from the legacy system is not possible within your current business constraints.
2. The legacy system contains essential features not also provided by the newer system.

The problem with legacy systems is the company/developers have no obligation to continue maintaining it.

This specific error message means that:

1. If you set your target to Flash Player 14 or higher, it will use escape methods that are JSON compliant.
2. If that is incompatible with your external code you need to target Flash Player 13 or lower.

"JSON compliance" or "JSON conventions" just means that any characters that are special to JSON will be escaped to prevent potential errors

Comment: I'm not sure if the word "target to Flash Player 14" mean user who access my site will use Flash Player 14 or my Flash Builder should be build to target Flash Player 14. If it's the later, I have not update the SDK for a long time. What I afraid of is user who upgrade to new Flash Player will be able to all of my existing code or not. If not, what should I do in case of I cannot control user's flash player version.

Comment: "content published to earlier Flash Player versions continues to use the legacy escaping behavior." This means that what matters is what you set when you publish, not what the user has.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question!